# IHttpPromise<{}>, Observable<SomeType[]> how to make it work in http call?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, rxjs

I'm struggling with AngularJS, TypeScript, and RxJs.

I code in Typescript in component arch with rxJs. **But its still AngularJs** ;)

I have defined the interface Car with id, brand and model fields as strings that match the API.

Now I'm making an HTTP call to rest API, and it gives me an error when I try to use that interface to define a type. 
I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Maybe too much Angular 6 way.

I have a variable

```
public cars$: Observable<Car[]>;
```

Now in a constructor, I'm trying to get cars from the API...

```
this.cars$ = fromPromise(this.$http.get('http://...someurl...')).pipe(map((data: IHttpResponse<{}>) => data));
```

How should I change `data: IHttpResponse<{}>` line to make it work with the Car type?

I've tried dozens of variations and get an error

> "Type Observable not assignable to type Observable<{}>" "Argument not assignable to the parameter" "Types of source and source are incompatible"...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you in `angularjs` or `angular` ?? which version ?

Comment: As I said at the top. Angular js 1.6.9

Comment: I changed the tag to `angularjs` but this code looks very much like Angular v2+?

Comment: Because I'm trying to learn how to upgrade my old projects in angularJS to Angular2+, so I code in Typescript in component arch with rxJs. But its still AngularJs ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the type definition for [IHttpResponse](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/angular/index.d.ts#L1632)

```
interface IHttpResponse<T> {
    data: T;
    status: number;
    headers: IHttpHeadersGetter;
    config: IRequestConfig;
    statusText: string;
    /** Added in AngularJS 1.6.6 */
    xhrStatus: 'complete' | 'error' | 'timeout' | 'abort';
}
```

we see that it will have a member `data` of type T. We can tell typescript what T is by putting the type in the diamonds<>

```
IHttpResponse<Car[]>
```

Replacing the generics with the type our interface now looks like this

```
interface IHttpResponse {
    data: Car[];
    status: number;
    headers: IHttpHeadersGetter;
    config: IRequestConfig;
    statusText: string;
    /** Added in AngularJS 1.6.6 */
    xhrStatus: 'complete' | 'error' | 'timeout' | 'abort';
}
```

So we want our function to look something like this:

```
(response: IHttpResponse<Car[]>) =>{ 
    //looking at the above interface we see that response.data is now Car[];
    const carArray:Car[] = response.data 
    return carArray;
}
```

Map returns an Observable of what we return so it will match your variable declaration `cars$: Observable<Car[]>;`

I Suspect type info is getting lost when calling `fromPromise()` and passing in [get](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/angular/index.d.ts#L1500). Try providing fromPromise the type info

```
fromPromise(this.$http.get<Car[]>('http://...someurl...'))
```

Comment: Ok, but... When I do that it gives me an error 
"Argument of type 'UnaryFunction<Observable<IHttpResponse<Car[]>>, Observable<Car[]>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UnaryFunction<Observable<IHttpResponse<{}>>, Observable<Car[]>>'.
  Types of parameters 'source' and 'source' are incompatible.
    Type 'Observable<IHttpResponse<{}>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<IHttpResponse<Car[]>>'.
      Type 'IHttpResponse<{}>' is not assignable to type 'IHttpResponse<Car[]>'.
        Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Car[]'.
          Property 'length' is missing in type '{}'."

Comment: And that's why I want to upgrade some projects to Angular2+. It works much easier there...

The funny thing is that I tried your solution, but I was confused why it is still buggy. I would have never picked that type after http.get.

Comment: Yeah it's a tricky one to debug. if you check out this [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Lorem%3CT%3E%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20ipsum%20%3D%20new%20Lorem()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A) and hover over` ipsum` you will see `const ipsum: Lorem<{}>` which means when no generic type is specified it defaults to `{}`. Thanks for the question helped me learn more about generics